# bars independent on shinobi chart

Tags: ios, shinobi

Using [shinobi charts](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/shinobicharts), 
is there any of the existing series that can be combine or tweak like the graph image below?

Its basically bars that are independent on chart, they do NOT start a 0.

***(optional)***  that each bar has a bottom and top label.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the problem by combing Scatter Series and Line Series

Still need some tweaking but its worked
[image]

**View Controller .h file**

```
@interface ScatterHRModifiedLineViewController : UIViewController<SChartDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *chartView;

@end
```

**View Controller  .m file**

```
#import "ScatterHRModifiedLineViewController.h"
#import "ScatterHRModifiedLineGraphDataSource.h"

@interface ScatterHRModifiedLineViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) ScatterHRModifiedLineGraphDataSource *datasource;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ShinobiChart *chart;
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGRect chartFrame;

@end


@implementation ScatterHRModifiedLineViewController

@synthesize chartView;

//MARK: - Lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //chart init
    CGFloat margin = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ? 10.0 : 30.0;
    self.chart = [[ShinobiChart alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.chartView.bounds, margin, margin)];

    [self.chartView addSubview:self.chart];
    self.chart.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    //data source setup
    self.datasource = [[ScatterHRModifiedLineGraphDataSource alloc]init];
    self.chart .datasource = self.datasource;

    [self setupChart];
    [self setupTheme];
    [self setupHorizontalLegend];
}//eom

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    self.chart= nil;
    self.datasource = nil;
}//eom

#pragma mark - Setup
-(void)setupChart
{
    self.chart.title = @"Heart Rates chart";

    self.chart.delegate = self;

    self.chart.crosshair = [[SChartSeriesCrosshair alloc]init];

    //Legend
    self.chart.legend.hidden = YES;

    //License Key
    self.chart.licenseKey = [[Constants shared] getLicenseKey];

    /* X Axis */
    self.chart.xAxis = [SChartDateTimeAxis new];
    self.chart.xAxis.title = @"Date";
    self.chart.xAxis.labelFormatString = @"MM dd yy";
    self.chart.xAxis.defaultRange = [self.datasource getInitialDateRange];
    self.chart.xAxis.style.majorGridLineStyle.showMajorGridLines = YES;
    self.chart.xAxis.style.majorTickStyle.showLabels = NO;
    self.chart.xAxis.style.majorTickStyle.showTicks = YES;
    self.chart.xAxis.style.minorTickStyle.showTicks = YES;
    self.chart.xAxis.majorTickFrequency = [[SChartDateFrequency alloc]initWithDay:2];

    //axis movement
    self.chart.xAxis.enableGesturePanning = YES;
    self.chart.xAxis.enableGestureZooming = YES;
    self.chart.xAxis.enableMomentumPanning = YES;
    self.chart.xAxis.enableMomentumZooming = YES;


    /* Y Axis */
    self.chart.yAxis = [SChartNumberAxis new];
    self.chart.yAxis.defaultRange = [[SChartRange alloc]initWithMinimum:@60 andMaximum:@120];;
    self.chart.yAxis.title = @"Heart Rates";
    self.chart.yAxis.majorTickFrequency = @1;
    self.chart.yAxis.style.majorGridLineStyle.showMajorGridLines = YES;
    self.chart.yAxis.style.majorTickStyle.showLabels = NO;
    self.chart.yAxis.style.majorTickStyle.showTicks = YES;
    self.chart.yAxis.style.minorTickStyle.showTicks = YES;

    //axis movement
    self.chart.yAxis.enableGesturePanning = NO;
    self.chart.yAxis.enableGestureZooming = NO;
    self.chart.yAxis.enableMomentumPanning = NO;
    self.chart.yAxis.enableMomentumZooming = NO;


}//eom

-(void)setupTheme
{
    SChartTheme * theme = [SChartiOS7Theme new];

    UIColor *darkGrayColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:83.0/255 green:96.0/255 blue:107.0/255 alpha:1];
    theme.chartTitleStyle.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
    theme.chartTitleStyle.textColor = darkGrayColor;
    theme.chartTitleStyle.titleCentresOn = SChartTitleCentresOnChart;
    theme.chartStyle.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    theme.legendStyle.borderWidth = 0;
    theme.legendStyle.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
    theme.legendStyle.titleFontColor = darkGrayColor;
    theme.legendStyle.fontColor = darkGrayColor;
    theme.crosshairStyle.defaultFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    theme.crosshairStyle.defaultTextColor = darkGrayColor;

    [self styleAxisStyle:theme.xAxisStyle useLightLabelFont:YES];
    [self styleAxisStyle:theme.yAxisStyle useLightLabelFont:YES];
    [self styleAxisStyle:theme.xAxisRadialStyle useLightLabelFont:NO];
    [self styleAxisStyle:theme.yAxisRadialStyle useLightLabelFont:NO];


    [self.chart applyTheme:theme];
}//eom

#pragma mark - Setup Helpers
- (void)styleAxisStyle:(SChartAxisStyle *)style useLightLabelFont:(BOOL)useLightLabelFont
{
    UIColor *darkGrayColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:83.0/255 green:96.0/255 blue:107.0/255 alpha:1];

    style.titleStyle.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
    style.titleStyle.textColor = darkGrayColor;
    if (useLightLabelFont) {
        style.majorTickStyle.labelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    } else {
        style.majorTickStyle.labelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    }
    style.majorTickStyle.labelColor = style.titleStyle.textColor;
    style.majorTickStyle.lineColor = style.titleStyle.textColor;
    style.lineColor = style.titleStyle.textColor;
}//eom

- (void)setupHorizontalLegend
{
    self.chart.legend.hidden = NO;

    self.chart.legend.style.orientation = SChartLegendOrientationHorizontal;
    self.chart.legend.style.horizontalPadding = @10;
    self.chart.legend.position = SChartLegendPositionBottomMiddle;
    self.chart.legend.style.symbolAlignment = SChartSeriesLegendAlignSymbolsLeft;
    self.chart.legend.style.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
}//eom
```

**Data Source .h file**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <ShinobiCharts/ShinobiCharts.h>

@interface ScatterHRModifiedLineGraphDataSource : NSObject<SChartDatasource>


-(SChartDateRange *)getInitialDateRange;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dataCollection;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *afterData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *beforeData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *seriesNames;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;

@end
```

**Data Source .m file**

```
    #import "ScatterHRModifiedLineGraphDataSource.h"

@implementation ScatterHRModifiedLineGraphDataSource


-(id)init {
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        self.seriesNames = @[@"before", @"after"];

        //date formatter
        self.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];

        //data
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"scatter-HRModified-data" ofType:@"plist"];
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
            NSArray * tempData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

            if ( [tempData count] == 2)
            {
                self.dataCollection = tempData;
                self.beforeData = [self.dataCollection objectAtIndex:0];
                self.afterData = [self.dataCollection objectAtIndex:1];

                NSLog(@"Data: %@", self.dataCollection);
            }
        }

    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Graph Helpers

//assuming all data points have the same dates
-(NSDate *)getDateFromIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSDate * date = [NSDate date];
    if (index < [self.afterData count])
    {
        NSDictionary * dateData = [self.afterData objectAtIndex:index];
        NSString * dateString = [dateData objectForKey:@"Date"];
        date = [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    }

    return date;
}//eom

-(id)getBeforeHeartRateValueForIndex:(NSInteger)dataIndex
{
    NSDictionary * currData = self.beforeData[dataIndex];

    id yValue = currData[@"Value"];

    return yValue;
}//eom


-(id)getAfterHeartRateValueForIndex:(NSInteger)dataIndex
{
    NSDictionary * currData = self.afterData[dataIndex];

    id yValue = currData[@"Value"];

    return yValue;
}//eom


#pragma mark - Multi part methods
-(SChartDateRange *)getInitialDateRange
{
    NSInteger lastIndex = [self.afterData count];
    lastIndex = lastIndex-1;

    NSDate * minDate = [self getDateFromIndex:0];
    NSDate * maxDate = [self getDateFromIndex:lastIndex];
    SChartDateRange * range = [[SChartDateRange alloc]initWithDateMinimum:minDate andDateMaximum:maxDate];

    return range;
}//eom

#pragma mark - Datasource methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSeriesInSChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart
{
    NSInteger total = 0;

    //making sure data is avaliable
    if ([self.afterData count] > 0) {
        total = 2 + [self.afterData count];
    }

    return total;
}//eom

-(SChartSeries *)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart seriesAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    UIColor * shinobiBlueColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1/255.f *.8 green:122/255.f *.8 blue:255/255.f *.8 alpha:1.f];
    UIColor * shinobiGreenColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:76/255.f *.8 green:217/255.f *.8 blue:100/255.f *.8 alpha:1.f];
    UIColor * lightGrayColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:238/255.f  green:238/255.f blue:238/255.f alpha:1.0f];

    SChartSeries * series = nil;

    //scatter
    if (index < 2)
    {
        NSString * seriesTitle;
        UIColor * seriesColor;

        if (index == 0)
        {
            seriesTitle = @"Before";
            seriesColor =  shinobiBlueColor;
        }
        else {
            seriesTitle = @"After";
            seriesColor = shinobiGreenColor;
        }

        SChartScatterSeries * beforeAndAfterSeries = [SChartScatterSeries new];

        //Styling
        beforeAndAfterSeries.title = seriesTitle;

        //Points
        beforeAndAfterSeries.style.pointStyle.showPoints = YES;
        beforeAndAfterSeries.style.pointStyle.radius = @10;
        beforeAndAfterSeries.style.pointStyle.innerColor = seriesColor;

        //labels
        beforeAndAfterSeries.style.dataPointLabelStyle.showLabels = YES;
        beforeAndAfterSeries.style.dataPointLabelStyle.offsetFromDataPoint = CGPointMake(0, -15);
        beforeAndAfterSeries.style.dataPointLabelStyle.displayValues = SChartDataPointLabelDisplayValuesY;


        series = beforeAndAfterSeries;
    }
    //lines
    else
    {
        SChartLineSeries * lineSeries = [SChartLineSeries new];

        SChartLineSeriesStyle * seriesStyle = [[SChartLineSeriesStyle alloc]init];
        seriesStyle.lineWidth = @3;
        seriesStyle.lineColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

        [lineSeries set_style:seriesStyle];

        lineSeries.showInLegend = false;


        series = lineSeries;
    }

    //crosshair
    series.crosshairEnabled = true;

    return series;
}//eom



-(id<SChartData>)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart
       dataPointAtIndex:(NSInteger)dataIndex
       forSeriesAtIndex:(NSInteger)seriesIndex
{
    SChartDataPoint *dp = [SChartDataPoint new];

    NSDate * date = [self getDateFromIndex:dataIndex];

    //heart rate values

    id beforeHeartRateValue = 0;
    id afterHeartRateValue = 0;
    id heartRateValue = 0;

    //scatter points
    if(seriesIndex < 2)
    {

        if (seriesIndex == 0)
        {
            heartRateValue = [self getBeforeHeartRateValueForIndex:dataIndex];;
        }
        else if (seriesIndex == 1)
        {
            heartRateValue = [self getAfterHeartRateValueForIndex:dataIndex];
        }
    }
    //lines connecting data points
    else
    {
        //series index == array index
        //data index == before or after array

        NSInteger currSeriesIndex = seriesIndex-2;
        date = [self getDateFromIndex:currSeriesIndex];


        if (dataIndex == 0)
        {
            heartRateValue = [self getBeforeHeartRateValueForIndex:currSeriesIndex];
        }
        else if (dataIndex == 1)
        {
            heartRateValue = [self getAfterHeartRateValueForIndex:currSeriesIndex];
        }
    }

    dp.xValue = date;
    dp.yValue = heartRateValue;

    return dp;
}//eom




-(NSInteger)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart
numberOfDataPointsForSeriesAtIndex:(NSInteger)seriesIndex
{
    //assuming all series have the same amount of data
    if (seriesIndex < 2)
    {
        return [self.afterData count];
    }
    //line series only need to high/low
    else
    {
        return 2;
    }

}//eom



@end
```

**P list data**

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Value</key>
            <integer>94</integer>
            <key>Date</key>
            <string>08-19-2016</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Value</key>
            <integer>90</integer>
            <key>Date</key>
            <string>08-20-2016</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Value</key>
            <integer>90</integer>
            <key>Date</key>
            <string>08-22-2016</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Value</key>
            <integer>89</integer>
            <key>Date</key>
            <string>08-23-2016</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Value</key>
            <integer>70</integer>
            <key>Date</key>
            <string>08-19-2016</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Value</key>
            <integer>75</integer>
            <key>Date</key>
            <string>08-20-2016</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Value</key>
            <integer>68</integer>
            <key>Date</key>
            <string>08-22-2016</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Value</key>
            <integer>87</integer>
            <key>Date</key>
            <string>08-23-2016</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</array>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

**DISCIAMER:** I work for ShinobiControls.

I'd recommend implementing this with an SChartCandlestickSeries.

A candlestick series takes four values: high, open, low & close.

If you set the high & open value to be equal along with the low and closed value. This should produce the floating bar series you're after.